# website to app converted app from Android studio doesn't install in mobile

Tags: java, android

I tried to convert youtube site to app using android studio, i followed a tutorial in youtube itself.

after adding the required code that showed in that tutorial, i generated the app. and copied it to mobile to install and see. 
But unfortunately i t isn't installing.

I did exactly like the tutorial..

The code i have added goes as:

MyActivity Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.acer.usmlebuzz">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyActivity.Java

```
package com.example.acer.usmlebuzz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Activity main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.acer.usmlebuzz.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="587dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

thats all the code i have added, rest i got it from default project opening,.

Is there any i have missed.?

[image goes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dTw2.png)

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: What do you mean its not installing? do you have logs to go with your observation?

Comment: @JamesWahome @litelite No, i don't have any error messages, except the one tells me as `This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints` i have attached the screenshot of it to the question..

Comment: @HarishKolliparat consider adding your layout file  (activity_main) to the question since your error mentions Views

Comment: @JamesWahome I have added the activityMain.xml file code, please check

Comment: @JamesWahome Did i done anyting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Enable installing from external source.
1. Enable developer mode
2. Enable USB debugging
3. install from android studio

Comment: i did , the instal from external source, enabled developer mode, enabled usb debugging, yet app isn't installing..

Comment: ok, did you accept the debuggking key - the phone shows to you a fingerprint (series of hex values that identify the key) when you connect the phone for the first time with ADB enabled

like this: ( https://img.gadgethacks.com/img/03/28/63567129878697/0/android-basics-enable-developer-options-usb-debugging.w1456.jpg )

Comment: i actually downloaded the converting apk file to my mobile through dropbox. should i not do like that?

Comment: absolutely not!
This is not the way it is supposed to be done. <br/>
From android studio menu: Run->Run app <br />
or press the green play button in the toolbar. Btw you can find plenty of material online - use videos on youtube to get started - udacity provides a free course in partnership with Google: https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837